# Why blender 2.9 looks like this when I use solid mode with some geometry?

Tags: 3d-view

I had this problem with some imported geometry, and then using de Bsurface add on. I don´t know if it´s a bug, or if its my GPU.
I don´t have any problem when rendering btw, nor do I with material preview [image]

Comment: Are you using cycles or evee to render this?

Comment: It´s not rendered, it´s on solid mode. I changed between Cycles and Evee, but its the same

Comment: Most likely some GPU issue - unsupported GPU, out of date drivers, or (less likely) card going bad. Check here to make sure your GPU is supported in blender 2.8+   -   https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/ - If you're supported,. make sure your drivers are up to date (although be wary of certain driver versions for AMD cards).